# Particular Constructor was called before the Method is called

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

```
class EmployeeBase : Base
{
    protected IDependency _dependency;

    ctor(IDependency dependency)
    {
       _dependency = dependency;
    }
    ctor(string name, int age)
    {
        base.Initialize("XXX " + name, "YYY" + Age);
    }


    IList<Emp> GetAllEmployees()
    {
       return _dependency.GetRecords();
    }
}

class FilteredEmployeeBase : EmployeeBase
{
    ctor(string name, int age) : base(name, age){}
    IList<Emp> GetMatchingEmployees()
    {
       return _dependency.GetRecords();
    }
}


// To Test Get GetMatchingEmployees, All i have to do is Inject IDependency and check assert was called on _dependency.GetRecords...
```

But the key thing here is... the base classes overloaded constructor should have been called - How do test this in Rhino Mocks

*Pls Note: Except FilteredEmployeeBase rest all are legacy code & i don't have control over changing them.*

Comment: Which overload are you interested in checking?  Your question as it stands is very unclear.

Comment: The base class constructor will be called, what is the question here?

Comment: Oops sorry for being unclear....

Let me change my requirement.... All i wanted to confirm is whether base.Initialize method in overloaded constructor is called before _dependency.GetRecords() is called - Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Also assume you have a default constructor ctor() in FilteredEmployeeBase

Answer (score 0):

If you call `FilteredEmployeeBase.GetMatchingEmployees` without calling the base class constructor taking the `dependency`, then the call will fail on `_dependency` being null. So a successful call on `GetMatchingEmployees` is sufficient I would say. Or do I miss something?

Comment: `FilteredEmployeeBase` doesn't call the dependency constructor... how do you know that's the overload the op is asking about?